# Does Cobalt support 2017 EME?

Tags: html, cobalt

1. I can find the interface as follow:

   ```
   partial interface Navigator {
     Promise<MediaKeySystemAccess> requestMediaKeySystemAccess (DOMString keySystem, sequence<MediaKeySystemConfiguration> supportedConfigurations);
   };
   ```

   This interface is specified by 2017 EME, but I cannot find its implementation.
   **So Does Cobalt support 2017 EME?**
2. If Cobalt will support 2017 EME, When will Cobalt finish this feature support?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cobalt supports EME 16 March 2017 in both master and RC_9 branches.

Comment: Why does Cobalt have no implementation of "requestMediaKeySystemAccess" which is specified by 2017 EME ?
If Cobalt has no this interface, we cannot run 2017 QE EME sub-page.

Comment: There is an implementation, but you have to set `cobalt_media_source_2016` to 1 in your `gyp_configuration.gypi` for it to be compiled.